# AD users in B2C tenant

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am wondering if it is possible to let's say *connect* the Azure AD with the Azure B2C, in order that the Azure AD users are able to login in my custom policy. I already implemented one, including MFA.

I was reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy), but I am not sure if it is the right way. If so, I see I have to specify the `client-id`. What if I have more than one application using this policy, do I have to create a policy for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked approach is correct. You specify a clientId which represents AADB2C user-flow/custom-policy as an “Application” to the AAD IdP. So this relationship can be used per AAD B2C user-flow/custom-policy or shared across all your custom policies and user flows.

It can be useful to have separate registrations at AAD so that you could target them individually for conditional access.

Comment: So, if I have 10 web apps, I'd have 10 Azure application registrations...does it mean I'd have to create 10 policies? Or should I define just 1 Azure application and use it on all my web apps?

Comment: You can have 10 web apps, and they can all connect to  1 AAD B2C policy.

Comment: Ok at the end I got it. Thanks.